# How to find and click a table element by text using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

```
<tr id="item" ng-repeat="item in itemList>
   <td id="code" ng-repeat="column in columns">Some Text</td>
</tr>
```

I've seen some other similar questions but I couldn't solve it yet.
Thats what I've tried so far:

```
element.all(by.repeater('column in columns')).findElement(by.id('code')).getText('Some Text').click();
```

**EDIT:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items>
<td>{{item.name}}</td>
<td>{{item.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

Which results in:

```
<tr>
<td>Some Name</td>
<td>Some Text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>More Name</td>
<td>More Text</td>
</tr>
```

etc etc

Comment: I think **protractor** comes in picture when you are about to make a `$http` request.

Comment: <td> will got same id in the loop, try <td id="row_{{$index}}">  and use findElement(by.id('row_0')) to click first row. And if you have unique 'id' across page, no need to select by.repeater('column in columns') before. I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) the desired element:

```
var columns = element.all(by.repeater('column in columns'));
columns.filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text == 'Some Text';
    });
}).first().click();
```

Comment: thanks, protractor says that cannot click on undifined, so I presume that protractor didnt found any element, but there is element with the text i wrote

Comment: i've made some changes at 1st post, to get it right in a more simple example